# AppEngine: logging events from the browser (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, python, google-app-engine, logging

Can someone show me an example of logging client-side events in JavaScript to AppEngine's server-side Python logging module? I'd like to log events of the same five severity levels, but from client-side code, not just server-side code as is described in the [App Engine logging docs](http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/logging.html).

If there's a built-in handler for logging, excellent. If not and I must write a server-side handler, I would love to see an example.

For those that are curious, I'm trying to build a UI entirely in the browser that only communicates with the server for data. It would be nice to log things that happen in the browser that wouldn't otherwise trigger a call to the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JavaScript isn't too complicated. Here is a JavaScript module modeled after Python's [`logging`](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html) module. It uses jQuery to POST the log message to the server at URLs like `/log/debug` or `/log/info`.

```
// logging.js
var logging = {};

logging.log = function log(lvl, msg) {
  $.ajax({
    url: "/log/" + lvl,
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "text/plain",
    data: msg,
  });
};

logging.debug = function debug(msg) {
  logging.log("debug", msg);
};

logging.info = function info(msg) {
  logging.log("info", msg);
};

logging.warning = function warning(msg) {
  logging.log("warning", msg);
};

logging.error = function error(msg) {
  logging.log("error", msg);
};

logging.critical = function critical(msg) {
  logging.log("critical", msg);
};

return logging;
```

To use it, simply make calls like `logging.info("log message here")`.

The server-side Python code to handle these requests isn't complicated. Here is the URL mapping.

```
# main.py (some stuff omitted for clarity)
import logging
import wsgiref.handlers
from google.appengine.ext import webapp

urlmap = [(r"/log/(.+)", handlers.LoggingHandler),]
application = webapp.WSGIApplication(urlmap)
wsgiref.handlers.CGIHandler().run(application)
```

And here is the logging handler.

```
# handlers.py
import logging
from google.appengine.ext import webapp

class LoggingHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
  def post(self, lvl):
    if lvl not in ("debug", "info", "warning", "error", "critical",):
      self.error(404)
      self.response.out.write("Unknown log level %s" % lvl)
      return
    msg = self.request.body
    getattr(logging, lvl)(msg)
    response = "Message logged: %s %s" % (lvl.upper(), msg))
    self.response.out.write(response)
```

Answer (score 2):

As to why you want to achieve this using client side code, beats me. But I don't think there is a default support for this in the app-engine. Plus it would unnecessarily add to your bandwidth bill if you want to detect your errors and then send it back to your server to be logged.

May I ask why you don't want to use normal `logging.debug`, `logging.info` and `logging.error` in python? You can even filter out your messages in the admin console by severity, time, what not.

### Edit

Wait, Do i understand this right -

1. You hit an error in your javascript - lets say for example's sake, an undefined var, while performing an operation.
2. You want to log this to your app-engine log

If this is the case, you can achieve this using simple ajax calls. Pseudo code provided below

```
//JS
//Make ajax call to a method on your server, providing
//error severity, error location, page, action performed

//Python
#Method which takes in error severity, plus other details mentioned above
#Based on the severity, use either, debug, info, error methods 
#(already available in the logging module) 
#to log your statements, which will then be available on your admin console
```

This is untested, but it should work as advertised

Comment: Thanks, Jibi. When I figure out the details I'll edit your answer to include example code and then mark it as the accepted answer. If you want to beat me to it, all the better.

Comment: @ChristopherJamesCalo - it's actually quite easy. If you actually do need sample code, let me know, and you're welcome.